# What does the tactic destruct do in the proof below?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I was reading the series Software Foundations by Benjamin Pierce. And in the Chapter Logic in the first book I came across a problem.
In the proof of the theorem

```
Theorem not_exists_dist :
  excluded_middle ->
  forall (X:Type) (P : X -> Prop),
    ~ (exists x, ~ P x) -> (forall x, P x).
```

where `excluded_middle` refers to

```
Definition excluded_middle := forall P : Prop,
  P \/ ~ P.
```

And the proof of theorem can be as follows:

```
Proof.
  unfold excluded_middle.
  intros exmid X P H x.
  destruct (exmid (P x)) as [H1 | H2].
  - apply H1.
  - destruct H.
    exists x. apply H2.
Qed.
```

What puzzled me is the `destruct H` in the second case. What does the tactic `destruct` do here? It seems different from What I've known about it before.
(`H` here is  `~ (exists x : X, ~ P x)`).
After using `destruct H`, the subgoal is tranformed from `P x` into `exists x : X, ~ P x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you destruct a term of the form `A -> B` you get a goal for `A` and the goals for what `destruct B` would result in. `not A` is defined as `A -> False` so `B` is `False` in your case and `destruct B` results in no goals. So you end up with just `A`.

Here is a long form proof of what is going on:

```
Theorem not_exists_dist :
  excluded_middle ->
  forall (X:Type) (P : X -> Prop),
    ~ (exists x, ~ P x) -> (forall x, P x).
Proof.
  unfold excluded_middle.
  intros exmid X P H x.
  destruct (exmid (P x)) as [H1 | H2].
  - apply H1.
  - assert(ex (fun x : X => not (P x))) as H3.
    exists x. apply H2.
    specialize (H H3).
    destruct H.
Qed.
```

Comment: You can also replace `destruct H` with `exfalso; apply H`.